# What is an efficient way to reset all values of a Vec<T> without resizing it?

Tags: vector, rust

I can use `resize`, but it seems like overkill because I do not need to resize the vector, just modify its values. Using a new variable is not an option, since this vector is actually a field in a struct.

I guess that `resize` is efficient, and probably the answer to my question, but its name does not carry the meaning of resetting the values without modifying the size.

In C, I would use `memset` (in opposition to `realloc`).

Illustration of my question:

```
let my_vec_size = 42;
let mut my_vec = Vec::new();       //  'my_vec' will always have a size of 42
my_vec.resize(my_vec_size, false); //  Set the size to 42, and all values to false

// [ ... ] piece of code where the values in 'my_vec' will be modified, checked, etc ...


// now I need to reuse my_vec.
// Possibility A -> use resize again
my_vec.resize(my_vec_size, false);

// Possibility B -> iterate on the vector to modify its values (long and laborious)
for item in my_vec.iter_mut() {
    *item = false;
}

// Possibility C ?
```

Comment: *" Using a new variable is not an option, since this vector is actually a field in a struct."* Ever heard of [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html)?

Comment: @hellow No, I'm still new to the language. Very nice discovery indeed, thanks for pointing it. But I'm not sure reallocating a chunk of memory would be more efficient than just modifying the values, what do you think ?

Comment: @m.raynal An empty vector does not allocate any memory in the heap

Comment: Indeed. But what about [`Vec::clear`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.clear)?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem, but for vector of `bool`s, you might want to consider switching to [`bit-vec`](https://crates.io/crates/bit-vec). `Vec<bool>` is not specialized like C++'s `std::vector<bool>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`resize` by itself will **not** work to "reset" values:

```
const LEN: usize = 3;

fn main() {
    let mut values = vec![false; LEN];

    values[0] = true;

    values.resize(LEN, false);
    println!("{:?}", values); // [true, false, false]
}
```

---

Just use a for loop:

```
for v in &mut values {
    *v = false;
}
println!("{:?}", values); // [false, false, false]
```

If that sight offends you, write an *extension trait*:

```
trait ResetExt<T: Copy> {
    fn reset(&mut self, val: T);
}

impl<T: Copy> ResetExt<T> for [T] {
    fn reset(&mut self, value: T) {
        for v in self {
            *v = value;
        }
    }
}
```

```
values.reset(false);
println!("{:?}", values); // [false, false, false]
```

The trait idea can be extended so that each value knows how to reset itself, if that makes sense for your situation:

```
trait ResetExt {
    fn reset(&mut self);
}

impl<T: ResetExt> ResetExt for [T] {
    fn reset(&mut self) {
        for v in self {
            v.reset();
        }
    }
}

impl ResetExt for bool {
    fn reset(&mut self) {
        *self = false;
    }
}

impl ResetExt for String {
    fn reset(&mut self) {
        self.clear();
    }
}
```

```
values.reset();
println!("{:?}", values); // [false, false, false]
```

Comment: Clear + Resize works pretty well, it just suffers from destroying and recreating the elements which may not be cheap.

Comment: From the doc of `Vec::resize`: "If `new_len` is greater than `len`, the Vec is extended by the difference, with each additional slot filled with `value`". Looks like I did not pay enough attention to the documentation on this point, thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 7):

The most efficient way in general is to reset the values themselves (aka B):

```
for item in &mut my_vec { *item = false; }
```

For booleans it is not immediately obvious, however for a `String` it is important to preserve the allocated buffer of each element:

```
for item in &mut my_vec { item.clear(); }
```

---

If discarding and recreating the elements of the `Vec` is cheap, such as the case of the boolean or if the elements will be overwritten anyway, then a combination of `clear` and `resize` is easier:

```
my_vec.clear();
my_vec.resize(my_vec_size, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

> In C, I would use `memset`

[`std::ptr::write_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write_bytes.html) uses `memset` internally, so you can (almost) precisely translate this code. An example from the Rust documentation:

```rust
let mut vec = vec![0u32; 4];
unsafe {
    let vec_ptr = vec.as_mut_ptr();
    ptr::write_bytes(vec_ptr, 0xfe, 2);
}
assert_eq!(vec, [0xfefefefe, 0xfefefefe, 0, 0]);
```